# How can I upload a file with a hidden_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, hidden-field

I have a form for uploading a file to my website:

```
<%= f.file_field :file %>
```

If I know the name of the file I want to upload, can I accomplish the same thing automatically with a hidden field? I can't find syntax for this anywhere in the rails docs.

Comment: If you mean can you upload a file from the users computer without them explicitly consenting (i.e. pressing a browse button and choosing a file), no.

Comment: @Kris Damn, I never thought of how badly you could abuse that. Of course that's not possible.

Comment: I don't think that is possible and it is discouraged to upload a file without user's consent.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible because it would allow the browser to take any file on the users computer without their permission :)

Uploading a file via a browser requires explicit consent on the part of the user by way of pressing the "browse" button and choosing a file.

You would need the user to install a custom application which does this instead of using a browser.

Comment: Could such an application be written in Rails?

Comment: Not really. Rails is a web *server* framework. The app would be a *client*, installed on every users computer. It could be written in Ruby, but typically it would be written in a compiled language (for ease of install), you might want to check Crystal (https://crystal-lang.org/) out which has a Ruby-like syntax.